# Localization of storyboards

Tags: ios, string, localization, storyboard

My application uses base localization in Russian and additional in English languages.
I localize storyboards using strings and the most of them localized well.
But I have a stubborn storyboard which localized only partially.
Three of ten strings localized well and looks correctly if I change their values in a strings file.
But other seven elements do not read values from strings file.
I tried to delete the app, removed derived data - nothing helped.
What to do with it?